# Android, appcompat v21, implement scrolling techniques

Tags: android, scroll, android-appcompat

In [http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling) described  scrolling techniques.
But I have not found details of how to implement it.
I'm trying to implement "*Flexible space with image*" anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 7):

I think this lib perfectly suits your need :

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

It includes all the scrolling techniques described in the Google design specs and more.
Moreover, it brings support for `ListViews`, `GridViews`, `ScrollViews`, `RecyclerViews` and `WebViews`.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this blog post](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/) has what you're looking for. It offers a guide to make a layout similar to that (although you might have to add some code to color the app bar).

The grand idea behind this sort of "layout trick" is to implement a `ScrollView` with some sort of `onScrollChanged` listener. The aim is to make your `Activity` aware of scroll changes and then could transform the required elements.

Once you could get a sense of the scroll position (and changes) you could use that value as a base to apply color transformation (for the `ActionBar`'s background) and to rescale the header text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to use Toolbar instead of ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

Late but not least,

You need to you use [Android Support Design Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) v22 or Above. Specifically CoordinatorLayout with AppBar Layout and Toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

as mentioned in android Developer [Blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) 
also described in [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32i7ot0y78U) by Ian Lake